# What is the best way to hide struct fields and yet make it synchronise access and modification of fields?

Tags: json, go, struct, concurrency, mutex

Here is a problem I am facing with a golang struct

```
 type User struct {
     name  string `json:"name"`
     email string `json:"email"`
 }
```

Now I want the access and modification of this struct fields to be concurrent safe
And hence have added a mutex and added methods which locks the mutex
The user code can now access and mutate only via methods and cannot directly access the fields

```
type User struct {
     name string  `json:"name"`
     email string `json:"email"`
     sync.RWMutex `json:"-"`
}

func (u *User) Name() string {
   u.RLock()
   defer u.RUnlock()

   return u.name  
}

func (u *User) Email() string {
   u.RLock()
   defer u.RUnlock()

   return u.email  
}

func (u *User) SetName(p string) {
   u.Lock()
   defer u.Unlock()

   u.name = p  
}

func (u *User) SetEmail(p string) {
   u.RLock()
   defer u.RUnlock()

   u.email = p  
}
```

So far so good but the problem is json/bson marshalling fails as it requires exported fields

So I implement custom marshalling which returns a similar struct but with exported fields

```
func (self User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var usr struct {
        Name  string `json:"name"` 
        Email string `json:"email,omitempty"`
        sync.RWMutex `json:"-"`
    }
    return json.Marshal(usr)
}

func (self *User) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    var usr struct {
        Name   string  `json:"name"`
        Email  string  `json:"email"` 
        sync.RWMutex   `json:"-"`
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &usr); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    self.name = usr.Name
    self.email = usr.Email

    return nil
}
```

But this does not completely make the User struct concurrency safe as the marhsaling code is not locked.

My question is how to make the marshalling code to use the same mutex?
Making the mutex global is not going to solve the problem as we create multiple instances of the struct.
The user struct declared in marshaling is different from the main User struct so locking on the mutex of inner struct is meaningless.

What's the best way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add a mutex to the values you marshal, that's pointless.

But you do need to use the `User`'s mutex while you copy or set its fields.

**Some important things:**

- If you embed a non-pointer mutex, you must specify all your methods with pointer receiver, else the lock will be copied!
- You do not need to specify `json` tags on unexported fields, that's redundant. And going further, since you provide your own marshaling logic, you don't even have to provide any `json` tags, since they won't be used at all. So this `User` is perfectly enough:

  ```
  type User struct {
      name  string
      email string
      sync.RWMutex
  }
  ```
- Even though `name` and `email` are unexported, those values are not "safe", as you provided an exported `MarshalJSON()` method which return those values (in JSON format). You still have compile-time safety about accessing `User.name` and `User.email`, but know that values they store are not secret.

**Example:**

```
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    u.RLock()
    usr := struct {
        Name  string `json:"name"`
        Email string `json:"email,omitempty"`
    }{u.name, u.email}
    u.RUnlock()

    return json.Marshal(usr)
}

func (u *User) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    usr := struct {
        Name  string `json:"name"`
        Email string `json:"email"`
    }{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &usr); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    u.Lock()
    u.name = usr.Name
    u.email = usr.Email
    u.Unlock()

    return nil
}
```

Comment: "If you embed a non-pointer mutex, you must specify all your methods with pointer receiver, else the lock will be copied!" : Done. We have a linter to check that. Had learnt this the hard way

Comment: "You don't have to add a mutex to the values you marshal, that's pointless." I understand what you are saying is since the struct is being initialized, there is no concurrent access issue at this point of time. Just like java constuctor cannot be declared synchronized. Thanks for confirming I was overthinking :-)

Comment: "Even though name and email are unexported, those values are not "safe", as you provided an exported MarshalJSON() method which return those values (in JSON format). You still have compile-time safety about accessing User.name and User.email, but know that values they store are not secret." You are right there but not of concern in my case.

Comment: But this does not prevent the go race detector to mark this as a data race. I can understand why as for it they are two functions concurrently accessing the same field. For now, have to ignore it

Comment: @rajeshnair This shouldn't cause a data race, as whenever fields of `User` are accessed, they are always protected by the mutex. You should not ignore data races. The code above does not have any races.

Comment: help me understand, this line `u.name = usr.Name` inside UnmarshalJSON() and user.GetName() can be accessed concurrently. In order to prevent it, I can use use the user.Lock() wherever consumer is called but that does not give me the control to make the User struct concurrency safe in one place

Comment: @rajeshnair Whenever fields of `User` are accessed (`u.name` and `u.email`), they are always between a lock and unlock calls, so that's safe. The value we pass on to marshal / unmarshal, that doesn't need synchronization, as that value is only available and accessed from a single goroutine.

Comment: But the marshalling goroutine and my own goroutine which acceses the value can run concurrently

Comment: @rajeshnair Yes, and? Variables that may be accessed from multiple goroutines are properly synchronized by the mutex, so that's not an issue.

Comment: the custom marshalling method does not have a mutex.Lock in it . That is the point I was trying to make

Comment: @rajeshnair No, but it does have `RLock()` in it, which is preferred if you only intend to read the protected variables.

Comment: if you see the question neither MarshalJSON nor UnmarshalJSON has Lock() or RLock() method called in it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180880/discussion-between-rajeshnair-and-icza).